# Why does this for loop execute five times and stop?

Tags: c++

```
int i, j;
for (i=0, j=5; i=j;)
{ 
    cout<<i<<j<<endl;  
    i++; 
    j--;
}
```

It executes five times:

```
55
44
33
22
11
```

When j=0, why does it stop?

Comment: Did you mean `i==j` in the for loops condition?

Comment: @GingerJack It's not the _condition check_, but initialization.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, thanks misread the , to ;.My bad.Corrected my comment.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it in a debugger?

Comment: @Angew Obviously they didn't :) ...

Comment: In each iteration it is assigning to to `i` the `j` value and when `j` reaches 0, it will stop the loop.  If you change `i=j` to `i==j` you will get an infinite loop.

Comment: @GingerJack It's still not correct.: _" i=j is true always. "_ That's not true.

Comment: yes got it now. condition fails when j value is 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `i=j` evaluates to the value of `i` after the assignment. And a zero value is `false` when evaluated in a boolean context. So whenever `i` is assigned the value `0`, the loop condition is `false` and the loop stops.

Answer (score 4):

```
for (i=0, j=5; i=j;)
```

sets `i` to `j` before every iteration. So the loop breaks as soon as `j == 0` which happens after you decreased `j` five times. An integer converted to a boolean expression results in `false` if it is zero, and `true` otherwise.

Note the difference between `=` (assignment) and `==` (comparison).